# Direct/Indirect object switching in reflexive verbs

Tags: verbes, verbes-pronominaux

I was a bit surprised to find out that while *attendre* takes a direct object, *s'attendre* takes an indirect object. E.g.

*Je l'attends* but *Je m'attends à lui*. Is it a widespread phenomena? Is there any pattern or is it necessary to memorize what kind of object each verb and its reflexive form expect?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, I just want to be that annoying guy who says "Je m'attends à lui" isn't French. Sorry !

Comment: Thanks, what's the French translation of "I'm expecting him" as opposed to "I'm awaiting him"?

Comment: @MonsieurTruite: I does sound correct to me, with the meaning “I expect him to be there”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai peut être été un peu trop sévère dans ma réponse ; je voulais dire que je ne pense pas que nous utilisions cette phrase dans le moindre contexte. J'aurais plutôt dû dire que ça ne "sonne" pas très Français..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In French, you can translate

> I'm expecting him.

by

> Je l'attends.

The sentence **"Je m'attends à lui."** does not look like a valid French syntax. The correct syntax would be

> Je m'attends à ce qu'il arrive bientôt.

which would translate too :

> I'm expecting him to arrive soon.

Comment: Merci, so *Je l'attends* means both 'I'm awaiting him' and 'I'm expecting him'?

Comment: Yes, both translation are correct. Note that "I'm awaiting him." is more formal. Therefore, it might be more accurate to say it translates too "I'm waiting for him." instead.

Comment: I see, thanks. When googling I encountered *je m'attends à toi*, so I thought it's valid french.

Comment: @dimid "Je m'attends à lui" is syntactically correct, just unidiomatic. For a more usual variant using the same verb valence, you could very well have someone enter a room, notice someone they didn't expect to be here (either because they expected someone else, or didn't expect anyone at all) and utter "Je ne m'attendais pas à toi" - i.e. "I didn't expect to see you here".

Comment: @Eauquidort merci, suppose you and your friend enter a room and notice someone, who you weren't expecting to see there. How would you say to your friend "I wasn't expecting to see him here"?

Comment: @dimid "Je ne m'attendais pas à le voir là"